# Advanced Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have started using elasticseach engine with my application, and I have encountered a problem.
I'm currently indexing as the following: each entry has its -

```
username
file_path
md5
```

My goal is to determine how many unique (count of 1 per username ) md5 are currently in the database.

I saw many approaches like using aggregations or counts operators by I havent managed to assemble the whole search query.
FYI, Im using python to execute the elasticsearch queries.

EDIT:
my script looks like this ATM:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

q = {
        "aggs" : {
            "distinct_colors" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "md5"
                    }
                }
            }
        }


res = es.search(index = "my-index", body = q, search_type="count", size = 0 )
for r in res['aggregations']['distinct_colors']['buckets']:
        print( r )
```

I have also used a "scan" approach but with no success:

Comment: Please mention what you have tried, also can you please mention the query in terms of  sql query, so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Query seems to work. What you see and what you expect to see?

Comment: I know this query works. It has two main problems; first, it only returns top 10 results instead of every reuslt. two, I want to name all the md5's in which has the count of 1.